# What are the default permissions of /etc/fstab?

Tags: permissions, fstab

I changed the permissions of my fstab file to 777. What were the default permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default permissions are 644.

```
$ ls -l /etc/fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 731 Abr 25 17:37 /etc/fstab
```